# Ajax GET returning entire page or just PHP response

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, get

From few days I'm trying to make this code work:

.PHP :

```
if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') && isset($_GET['tkn']) && isset($_GET['t'])) {
    $tkn = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['tkn']);
    $t = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['t']);
    if (time() < $t) {
        $info["msg"]="<strong>Error! </strong>link valid!";
        $info["cls"]="brand";
    }
    else {
        $info["msg"]="<strong>Error! </strong>Link expired!";
        $info["cls"]="danger";
    }
    $mysqli->close();
    json_encode($info);
}
```

.JS :

```
$.ajax({     
    url: window.location.href,
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    dataType: "JSON"
  });
```

If I use the current PHP code without adding **exit(json_encode($info));** It will return the entire **html** tag without any text returned by PHP code.

If I'm adding **exit(json_encode($info));** it will display only that code on white background.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Here's my login.php format

```html
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
 //some code goes here
 echo json_encode($info);
 exit;
 // this part is working perfectly, is getting the answer from php via ajax and display it in page(html part in running)
}
elseif ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') {
 //other code goes here
 echo json_encode($info);
 exit;
 // here is displayed only the message(without html part) if I add exit;
 //and if i dont add exit is displayed the message on white background on
    // the top of the page(html part is working);
?> 
//html part
```

Comment: how about `return  json_encode($info);` or `echo  json_encode($info);`

Comment: You're neither saving or echoing the result of `json_encode()`, nor are you telling the script to stop executing. When you use `exit()`, you dump the result and tell the script to stop executing.

Comment: @JacekBBudzynski ***echo json_encode($info);*** will add a white part with the php response on the top on the page and ***return json_encode($info);*** i will get an white page without noting on it.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I use the same format `exit(json_encode($info));` for post method and it seems to work. :( I don't understand why now isn't working.

Comment: _"echo json_encode($info); will add a white part with the php response on the top on the page"_ - You still need to kill the script after the echo. Do: `echo json_encode($info); exit;`. If that's not what you're looking for, then I have no clue what the expected result is.

Comment: I'm getting pretty confused now. _"If I use the current PHP code without..."_ <- that would return the complete page without the json-string, since you don't output the result nor exiting the script.. _"If I'm adding..."_ <- you see the json-string alone, right? That's because you're exiting and are outputting the result. What result are you actually expecting here?

Comment: You are sending your AJAX request to `window.location.href`, so the same URL the current document was already loaded from. So even though you are checking the request method and whether specific GET parameters are set - the result will still be the same for both (loading the page itself, and the AJAX request.) So of course you get your JSON data shown somewhere on the page - because your server-side script so far has no way of differentiating between both requests.

Comment: I edited my post and added more details.

Comment: And …? Is `login.php` what `window.location.href` contains when you make your AJAX request? If not, then how is this relevant to the question? Does the login.php get included anywhere else, or - what?

Comment: All im saying is why is working on post method and not working in get method. In post method (php) html tag is running after exit and in get method is not. Why?

Answer (score 0):

You need to print the json string after all

use

```
echo json_encode($info);
```